# FFMEG Adjust Brightness Runtime

Tags: ffmpeg, brightness, yuv

I use the following command to display yuv video;

```
ffmpeg -v debug -re -probesize 32 -buffer_size 500000 -protocol_whitelist file,rtp,udp -strict -2 -i test.106.sdp -pix_fmt yuv420p -f sdl "CH1"
```

test.16.sdp ;

```
v=0
o=IN IP4 10.0.1.19 
s=raw1
c=IN IP4 225.0.1.106/127
t=0 0
m=video 4378 RTP/AVP 96
a=rtpmap:96 raw/90000
a=fmtp:96 sampling=YCbCr-4:2:2; width=720; height=576; depth=8; colorimetry=BT.6
01-5; framerate=25;
```

I want to adjust brightness and contrast while displaying. How can i do this, any idea?

Han

Comment: Add eq filter and send commands to it. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/48635380

Comment: hi Gyan, sendcmp syntax is like; START[-END] COMMANDS so it depends on time but in my scenario, operator may change the parameters any time.

Comment: For immediate application, you would use `-1 COMMAND`

Comment: If I press 'c' it suggests the syntax;
  `Enter command: <target>|all <time>|-1 <command>[ <argument>]`
But the return value is **ret=-38** for the syntx;
   `all -1 brihtness 0` 
Is it mean that brightness is not supported for sendcmd?

Comment: Not with the spelling `brihtness`

Comment: sorry, I wanted to write **brightness**.

Comment: Share your full command.

Comment: command after press 'c';
`all -1 brightness 1`

Comment: I tried `all -1 brightness [1]` , `all -1 brightness 100`, `all -1 brightness -1` but nothing changed, always I got **ret=-38**

Comment: Try `eq -1 brightness VALUE`